# Persist form data during page transition in Asp.Net MVC 5 Jquery mobile Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I am working on a application (Asp.Net MVC 5 Jquery mobile Application) containing a form page. There are 3 buttons on the form page which go to other pages and take data from user for specific modules. But when user comes back to Main Form from those pages , he loses data which he put already in the form. It just gets flushed. I want to persist that data as well during page transitioning.

The solution I researched are about saving data in session but in my case the form fields in the main form are created dynamically.

I am unable to find out a way out that how can I persist main form data during page transitioning.

Any help?

Comment: Can you use `cookies`?

Comment: Same problem. Form elements are dynamic.

Comment: how much elements do you have? don't you want to serialize your form data to [base64 URL Safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL%5Fapplications) in cookies or session?

Comment: Is'nt it any way in jquery mobile to persist data during page transitioning?

Comment: Could you avoid the problem by using popups for the links instead of fully leaving the form? If not, use localstorage to store the form values before leaving the form, then when you dynamically rebuild the form, check localstorage as you add each element. Just make sure to remove the localstorage when the form is submitted.

Comment: That makes sense to me.